# Creating WPF window for pagination

Tags: wpf, vb.net

Am I on the right track?

The xml contains several groups of data including Default values, Page Header, Body data and Footer data. The main body of data is NOT broken down into page groups.

My plan is to extract the Page Header data and enumerate the body data in calculated groups (i.e. Header 1 will hold a page worth of data, then Header 2 will hold another page worth of data, etc.) and add the groups (Page Header, Body Data and Footer Data) to an ObservableCollection.

I will use an ItemsControl.ControlTemplate to add a 3 DockPanels. DockPanel0 will be Header row fixed height, DockPanel1 will hold body data and have fixed height as well, DockPanel2 will be the fixed height Footer. The overall size of the grid will be the size of the printed page.

My hope is that everytime the ObservableCollection encounters the header panel data it will add the a new header panel, etc. creating a second page and so on so forth.

This appears like it's going to take a lot of work as I still need to learn more about ControlTemplates and ObservableCollections.

What I need to know is, am I on the right track? Will this work? Any suggested reading, suggestions?

Comment: May be a headache.  What I don't like is spinning my wheels if I'm doing something wrong or there is a better way. If wpf can't do it then I will go back to a technology that I know can do the job and that's winforms. My reasons for trying wpf was the promise of rich content and little code. I'm willing to learn xaml (another code) if the results are achievable though. It appears like it will be easier to port to other platforms which also interests me.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is can be achieved using `DataTemplate`.

Read [this](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/01/03/itemscontrol-d-is-for-datatemplate/) article to learn about `DataTemplate`.

In short, `DataTemplate` is *how* you want to display the data (in your case `ObservableCollection`). You can basically provide a **template** (page header, body, footer) to your data to *render* in your UI.